# Set the y limits of an added average line of a plotly plot

Tags: r, plotly

I have created a basic plotly filled plot and I am trying to add an average line with:

```
library(plotly)
week<-c(2,1,3)
pts<-c(10,20,30)
wex<-data.frame(week,pts)
wex <- wex[order(wex$week), ]

plot_ly(x = ~wex$week, y = ~wex$pts, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', 
        fill = 'tozeroy')%>%
add_segments(x = 0, xend = max(wex$week), y = mean(wex$pts), yend =mean(wex$pts) )
```

but instead of a single line I get a whole area filled. I guess it has to do with `yend` argument but it does not make sense as it is the same as the `y` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the `fill='tozeroy'` is kept for the `add_segments()` call.

This works:

```
library(plotly)
week<-c(2,1,3)
pts<-c(10,20,30)
wex<-data.frame(week,pts)
wex <- wex[order(wex$week), ]
wex
plot_ly(x = ~wex$week, y = ~wex$pts, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', 
        fill = 'tozeroy')%>%
  add_segments(x = 0, xend = max(wex$week), y = mean(wex$pts), yend =mean(wex$pts),fill = 'none' )
```

I added `fill = 'none'` in `add_segments()`

Comment: great observation